# How do I keep a bar on the bottom of a page in IE 6,7,8 or how do I force IE to redraw the interface?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I need to glue a bar to the bottom of the client view in the web browser. Traditionally I would use position:fixed; except that I need to support my IE 6 clients. I've got a very extensive hack to glue the bar to the bottom of the page and over the content, however when the user scrolls  down or right, the bar stays fixed on the page.

To correct this issue I use a javascript event that gets fired using setInterval and when running the function in IE (8)'s debug tools the event fires and changes the position top and position left attributes but the page doesn't redraw the element. The code works but the element is not moving, see below.

[image: The example shown.]

Just so you know, the fix has to work in IE quirks mode... it can't work if the other IE versions are trying to use a standard. Believe me, I've tried.

P.S. This is really aggravating because I'm double checking IE9 support as well... get this the element does not move with the scroll bars in IE 6, 7, and 8 but moves in IE 9 and it still displays "IE Quirks Mode." And Microsoft said that this release wouldn't effect anything,...

HTML Structure

```
<body>
    <div id="j_zoom_area" style="zoom:100%;">
        The Application area the the zoom is changed (by the bar) for accessibility...
    </div>
    <div id="j_protectorite">
        <div class="j_bar">
        <div class="j_plate">Zoom Controls, Help, Search, other misc controls</div>
        <div class="j_plate">Copyright info, privacy policy, etc...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         j_doBar();
    </script>
</body>
```

The CSS for the bar is https://kscserver.com/ERP-API/Style/includes.css.
The particular javascript for the bar correction.

```
//This controls the scrolling of the bar
function j_FixBarSlowly(){
var nTop = 0;
var nLeft = 0;

nTop = (document.body.scrollTop + document.body.clientHeight) - 67;
nLeft = document.body.scrollLeft;

//document.title = document.body.scrollTop + '+' + document.body.clientHeight + '-67' + '=' + nTop + 'px';
document.getElementById("j_protectorite").style.Top = nTop + 'px';
document.getElementById("j_protectorite").style.Left = nLeft + 'px';
document.getElementById("j_protectorite").style.Bottom = '';
document.getElementById("j_protectorite").style.Position = 'absolute';

//Ie6,7,8 hack to force redraw

}

function j_doBar() {
//j_FixBarSlowly();

//if (setInterval != undefined) {
//  setTimeout("j_doBar();",5);
//} else {
    setInterval("j_FixBarSlowly();",5);
//}
}
```

Comment: if you've got the browser in quirks mode, you probably need to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your page (if you haven't got a doctype, it's no wonder you're having browser compatibility issues).

Comment: My personal favorite:  Un-IE6 them:  http://ie6update.com/  Evil genius!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing the best solution was to use an I Frame for the page content and have a div at the bottom of the page content. Of course a few javascript tweaks for proper sizing and you have a perfect solution.

Just for a visual reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an IE fix hack, such as [Dean Edwards' IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

This script runs when your page loads in IE and fixes some common problems in older versions of IE. [The documentation](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html) lists the things it deals with, and includes `position:fixed;`.

Hope that helps.

(Of course, the best solution - for your sanity - is just to give up trying to make IE6 look identical to newer browsers, and just live with a non-sticky footer in IE6. As long as it doesn't affect usability, I don't see a problem with IE6 users having a slightly less perfect page layout. But I know some people don't have the luxury of doing that; if your users are demanding it, they're the ones you have to listen to, not me!)

Comment: Unfortunately unless I can pull out the position:fixed fix out of that JS library, I can't use it. It upsets to many things that are working fine. To answer to your statement, about 50% (maybe less) of our clients use IE6 on old XP machines. We're stuck.

Comment: Another very important thing to note is the application only works well in IE Quirks Mode due to the support of IE6.

Comment: Even IE6 is better in standards mode with a doctype. (granted, it still has loads of issues, but it's better than without)

Comment: I've turned to an iframe solution, not the best idea but it does the trick. It also makes controlling page zoom so much easier. Thank you for the help, like I said under normal circumstances I'd prefer using a doctype and position:fixed.